# Unable to fetch the relevant links and discard others

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium along with BeautifulSoup to get the links leading to property details from a webpage. As the content are heavily dynamic, I made use of selenium to get the page source. When I run my script, I get lots of links including those required links.

***How can I get only the relevant link from each container out of the three?***

My try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def fetch_info(link):
    driver.get(link)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#community-search-homes .propertyWrapper > a")))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    linklist = [item.get("href") for item in soup.select("#community-search-homes .propertyWrapper > a")]
    return linklist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.khov.com/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    for newlink in fetch_info(url):
        print(newlink)
    driver.quit()
```

Results I'm having:

```
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-sienna-hills
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/affinity-at-verrado
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/four-seasons/k.-hovnanian's-four-seasons-at-victory-at-verrado
/find-new-homes/arizona/scottsdale/85255/k-hovnanian-homes/summit-at-silverstone
/find-new-homes/arizona/scottsdale/85257/k-hovnanian-homes/skye
/find-new-homes/arizona/phoenix/85020/k-hovnanian-homes/pointe-16
/find-new-homes/arizona/peoria/85383/k-hovnanian-homes/fusion-ii-at-the-meadows
/find-new-homes/arizona/scottsdale/85257/k-hovnanian-homes/aire
/find-new-homes/arizona/scottsdale/85255/k-hovnanian-homes/pinnacle-at-silverstone
/find-new-homes/arizona/peoria/85383/k-hovnanian-homes/montage-at-the-meadows
/find-new-homes/arizona/sun-city/85373/four-seasons/k.-hovnanian-s-four-seasons-at-ventana-lakes
/find-new-homes/arizona/peoria/85382/k-hovnanian-homes/park-paseo
/find-new-homes/arizona/laveen/85339/k-hovnanian-homes/affinity-at-montana-vista
/find-new-homes/arizona/laveen/85339/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-montana-vista
/find-new-homes/arizona/scottsdale/85255/k-hovnanian-homes/pinnacle-ii-at-silverstone
/find-new-homes/arizona/scottsdale/85255/k-hovnanian-homes/summit-ii-at-silverstone
```

Results I would like to get:

```
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-sienna-hills
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/affinity-at-verrado
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/four-seasons/k.-hovnanian's-four-seasons-at-victory-at-verrado
```

A chunk of html elements (`the link I'm after is within the second line of the following elements`):

```
<div class="propertyWrapper clear">
        <a href="/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-sienna-hills"><span class="link-outside"></span></a>
        <div class="propertyCarouselWrapper">
            <div class="responsiveImageCarousel enabled" style="touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                <div class="prevBtn"></div>
                <div class="nextBtn"></div>
                <div class="images" data-detail-url="/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-sienna-hills">
                    <ul style="width: 960px; left: 0px;">
                        <li style="width: 320px;"><img alt="holiday exterior new homes sienna hills usp" src="https://khovcachecdn.azureedge.net/azure/sitefinitylibraries/images/default-source/images/az/aspire-at-sienna-hills/community-thumbnails/holiday-exterior-new-homes-sienna-hills-usp.jpg?sfvrsn=4&amp;build=1019&amp;encoder=wic&amp;useresizingpipeline=true&amp;w=450&amp;h=280&amp;mode=crop"></li>
                        <li style="width: 320px;"><img alt="carnival exterior new homes sienna hills usp" src="https://khovcachecdn.azureedge.net/azure/sitefinitylibraries/images/default-source/images/az/aspire-at-sienna-hills/community-thumbnails/carnival-exterior-new-homes-sienna-hills-usp.jpg?sfvrsn=4&amp;build=1019&amp;encoder=wic&amp;useresizingpipeline=true&amp;w=450&amp;h=280&amp;mode=crop"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="pagination" style="width: 56px;"><ul><li class="active"></li><li></li></ul></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="propertyInfoWrapper">
            <div class="marker-details-container">
                <h3 class="marker-details">New Homes in Buckeye, Arizona</h3>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <h4 class="propertyListingHeader">Aspire at Sienna Hills</h4>
                <p class="marker-details">21007 West Almeria Road, Buckeye, AZ 85396</p>
                <p class="marker-details marker-status">Final Opportunities</p>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <p class="marker-details marker-price"><span class="bold">Priced from: </span>Mid $200s</p>
                <p class="marker-details"><span class="bold">Home type: </span>Single Family Homes</p>
                <p class="marker-details marker-amenities"><span class="bold">Amenities: </span>Pool, Hiking Trails, Park</p>
            </div>
            <div class="community-tag-container">
                <a href="/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-sienna-hills#quick-move-in-homes" onclick="KHOV.Analytics.trackEvent('Qmi_Icon_Qmi');">
                    <div class="community-tag">
                        <div class="ctaDesc quick-move-in-badge link-inside">Quick Move In Homes</div>
                        <div class="ctaIcon quick-move-in-badge-icon link-inside"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <a href="#request-info-form-modal" class="open-inline-modal-link" onclick="KHOV.Analytics.trackEvent('Orange_Ri_Request_Info');">
                <div class="button orange-color requestInfoButton link-inside" data-urlname="aspire-at-sienna-hills">Request Info</div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote!! Ain't my question clear enough to understand or it is much eaier to solve? Should I add few more details to bring the clarity If the post lacks anything? I'm really struggling how to create a good question!!!

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted. I think its a valid question, with clear example of what you are trying and your desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the featured id as well as results. You can use Or to combine. Latest bs4 supports `not`.

```
#propertyResultsContainer .propertyWrapper :not([onclick])[href*=find], #propertyFeaturedResultsContainer  .propertyWrapper :not([onclick])[href*=find]
```

This can also be shortened to

```
#propertyResultsContainer .propertyWrapper :not([onclick])[href*=find], #propertyFeaturedResultsContainer
```

But that shortening may be less robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for the desired keyword in the link and print those, and ignore the others:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.khov.com/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    for newlink in fetch_info(url):
        if url.split('/')[-1] in newlink:
            print(newlink)
    driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/aspire-at-sienna-hills
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/k-hovnanian-homes/affinity-at-verrado
/find-new-homes/arizona/buckeye/85396/four-seasons/k.-hovnanian's-four-seasons-at-victory-at-verrado
```

Comment: I'm playing with lots of different links like the one I've used within my script. So, any hardcoded string filtering won't be of any help if I go for another link. I wish to have any pure css selector solutions. Thanks @chitown88.

Comment: ok. you could use the keyword like a dynamic variable. I'm assuming you'll be feeding in the url, correct?

Comment: Your current solution will fail if you try out `https://www.khov.com/find-new-homes/arizona/casa-grande-city`. So, css selector solutions is still what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would list slicing works?

```
def fetch_info(link):
    driver.get(link)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#community-search-homes .propertyWrapper > a")))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    linklist = [item.get("href") for item in soup.select("#community-search-homes .propertyWrapper > a")][:3]
    return linklist
```